# How click in necessary coordinate x,y by Espresso in test?

Tags: android, testing, canvas, android-espresso, coordinate

I need click by Espresso testing in x, y.

I have view:

```
<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  class="uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarcompat.PullToRefreshLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="top"
      android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_layout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_param"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/palette_light_gray"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <example.ui.view.UnderlinedTextIndicator
            android:id="@+id/tab_indicator"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/field_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/field_padding"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date_param"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/tabbed_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tab_indicator"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <example.ui.BigButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_item"
            android:text="@string/btn_convert_rates"
            style="@style/BigButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</view>
```

So, in panel view: in top drawing date, under strings: text1 and text2 on one line, under some content, under - button.
I draw text1 and text2 on canvas. I need click on text1 and text2 by Espresso. But, if I write: `onView(withText(String.valueOf(R.string.text1))).perform(click());` - I have `android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "2131492993"`, So, I want click in coordinate x,y:

```
    private static ViewAction clickXY(final int x, final int y) {
        return new GeneralClickAction(
                Tap.SINGLE,
                new CoordinatesProvider() {
                    @Override
                    public float[] calculateCoordinates(View view) {

                        final int[] screenPos = new int[2];
                        view.getLocationOnScreen(screenPos);

                        final float screenX = screenPos[0] + x;
                        final float screenY = screenPos[1] + y;
                        float[] coordinates = {screenX, screenY};

                        return coordinates;
                    }
                },
                Press.FINGER);
    }
}
```

But, I do not know - which must be are x,y? How can to get x,y for test1 and x,y for test2?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to click an x,y coordinate here. 
That would not work well across screen sizes.

The problem is this code:

```
String.valueOf(R.string.text1)
```

R.string.text1 is an integer generated at build time and you are converting it to a string, so it is looking for some view that says "2131492993".

I assume you are trying to look up the string value from a resource file.

You want something like this:

```
onView(withText(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getString(R.string.text1))).perform(click());
```

Or even:

```
onView(withText("My Button Text")).perform(click());
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using

```
onView(withText(R.string.text1)).perform(click());
```

Note the difference - I am not using String.valueOf(R.string.text1). This is giving you the string "2131492993" instead it creates a Matcher which internally looks up the string associated with 2131492993 in your resource file and then finds a view containing that text.